# Uploading image with another form text input in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

i'm have confusing problem about uploading image in multiple input text like registration page. i found solution but the image is not save to database or folder.
please help me all...

my admin.php view

```html
<script>
  //upload img
$('#form').ajaxForm({
       //uploadimg is my form id            
        dataType: 'json',
        success: processJson
});
function processJson(data) {
        if(data.msg=="success"){
             alert('Upload sukses.');
        }
        else{
             alert('Upload gagal.');
        }
}

function add_edulibs()
{
    save_method = 'add';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
    $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string
    $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
    $('.modal-title').text('Tambah Data'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
}

function edit_edulibs(id)
{
    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
    $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('edulibs/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
            $('[name="nama"]').val(data.nama);
            $('[name="nim"]').val(data.nim);
            $('[name="pembimbing"]').val(data.pembimbing);
            $('[name="subyek"]').val(data.subyek);
            $('[name="judul"]').val(data.judul);
            $('[name="tanggal"]').datepicker('update',data.tanggal);
            $('[name="alamat"]').val(data.alamat);
            $('[name="kontak"]').val(data.kontak);
            $('[name="email"]').val(data.email);
            $('[name="penerbit"]').val(data.penerbit);
            $('[name="file_upload"]').val(data.gambar);
            $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error mendapatkan data');
        }
    });
}

</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Kelola Data</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body form">
            <form action="<?php echo base_url('edulibs/do_upload/')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/> 
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nama</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="nama" placeholder="Nama Lengkap" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">NIM</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="nim" placeholder="Nomor Induk Mahasiswa" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Pembimbing</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="pembimbing" placeholder="Nama Pembimbing" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Subyek</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="subyek" placeholder="Subyek" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Judul</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <textarea name="judul" placeholder="Judul Karya Tulis" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Tanggal Terbit</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="tanggal" placeholder="Tahun-Bulan-Hari" class="form-control datepicker" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Alamat</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <textarea name="alamat" placeholder="Alamat Lengkap" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Kontak</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="kontak" placeholder="Nomor Kontak" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="email" placeholder="Alamat e-mail" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Penerbit</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="penerbit" placeholder="Nama Penerbit" class="form-control" type="text">
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Foto</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="file" name="file_upload" />
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Batalkan</button>
            </div>
```

My edulibs.php controller

```html
public function admin()
 {
     $this->load->view('admin');
 }
function do_upload(){
        $config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/foto/";  
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|JPEG';
   $config['file_name'] = url_title($this->input->post('file_upload'));
   
  $this->upload->initialize($config); 
   if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file_upload'))
   {
   echo $this->upload->display_errors();
   }
   else{
   $data = array(
   'gambar'=>$this->upload->file_name
   );
   $this->edulib_model->insert($data,'edulib');
   }
    }
```

My edulib_model.php

```html
public function save($data)
 {
  $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
  return $this->db->insert_id();
 }

public function insert($data,$table){
  $this->db->insert($data,$table);
 }
```

Comment: didn't get: *problem about uploading image in multiple input text like registration page*

Comment: @Pathik Vejani please tell me the mean i don't understand?